# tf.gather with indices of higher dimention than input data?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Reading [Dynamic Graph CNN for Learning on Point Clouds](https://github.com/WangYueFt/dgcnn) code, I came across this snippet:

```
  idx_ = tf.range(batch_size) * num_points
  idx_ = tf.reshape(idx_, [batch_size, 1, 1]) 

  point_cloud_flat = tf.reshape(point_cloud, [-1, num_dims])
  point_cloud_neighbors = tf.gather(point_cloud_flat, nn_idx+idx_)  <--- what happens here?
  point_cloud_central = tf.expand_dims(point_cloud_central, axis=-2)
```

debugging the line I made sure that the dims are

```
point_cloud_flat:(32768,3) nn_idx:(32,1024,20), idx_:(32,1,1) 
// indices are (32,1024,20) after broadcasting
```

Reading the [tf.gather doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) I couldn't understand what the function does with dimensions higher that the input dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent function in numpy is `np.take`, a simple example:

```py
import numpy as np

params = np.array([4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8])

# Scalar indices; (output is rank(params) - 1), i.e. 0 here.
indices = 0
print(params[indices])

# Vector indices; (output is rank(params)), i.e. 1 here.
indices = [0, 1, 4]
print(params[indices])  # [4 3 6]

# Vector indices; (output is rank(params)), i.e. 1 here.
indices = [2, 3, 4]
print(params[indices])  # [5 7 6]

# Higher rank indices; (output is rank(params) + rank(indices) - 1), i.e. 2 here
indices = np.array([[0, 1, 4], [2, 3, 4]])
print(params[indices])  # equivalent to np.take(params, indices, axis=0)
# [[4 3 6]
# [5 7 6]]
```

In your case, the rank of `indices` is higher than `params`, so output is rank(`params`) + rank(`indices`) - 1 (i.e. 2 + 3 - 1 = 4, i.e. (32, 1024, 20, 3)). The `- 1` is because the `tf.gather(axis=0)` and `axis` must be rank 0 (so a scalar) at this moment. So the `indices` takes the elements of the first dimension (`axis=0`) in a "fancy" indexing way.

**EDITED**:

In brief, in your case, (if I didn't misunderstand the code)

- `point_cloud` is (32, 1024, 3), 32 batches 1024 points which have 3
  coordinates.
- `nn_idx` is (32, 1024, 20), indices of 20 neighbors of
  32 batches 1024 points. The indices are for indexing in `point_cloud`.
- `nn_idx+idx_` (32, 1024, 20), indices of 20 neighbors of
  32 batches 1024 points. The indices are for indexing in `point_cloud_flat`.
- `point_cloud_neighbors` finally is (32, 1024,
  20, 3), the same as `nn_idx+idx_` except that `point_cloud_neighbors` are their 3 coordinates while `nn_idx+idx_` are just their indices.

Comment: so the 2d input array is flattened, taken by indices and becomes 3D , and then back to be compatible with the last shape of the input? now the `idx_ = tf.range(batch_size) * num_points`

Comment: The `point_cloud_flat` is just as it is. But the gather operation is done on the first dimension (`axis=0`) by default. The last shape is not involved in this gather operation. I updated the answer, see if it is clearer.